# CSA certified products can't be commissoned with Google ecosystem

Tags: google-smart-home

Our produt already obtained the CSA Matter certification. While can't be paired by customers. My understanding is if the device is certified in the CSA DCL, even not registered in the Google developer console, customer can use the Matter in google ecosystem.

If the device is certified in the CSA DCL, can used in google system, even not verified in google system.

Answer (score 0):

All CSA certified Matter products should work with Google Home regardless of registering in Google Developer Console.

However, when you create a project in the console you have access to additional features such as customized pairing image and OTA firmware updates. Also, registered users are  able to use their own apps as commissioners in Android devices.

If you continue seeing the issue with pairing CSA certified Matter devices with Google Home, please open a ticket in [Public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) for further debugging and share the same information there. I’m going to follow up with the team and update you through the issue tracker.